# I have to reboot mac to restart bluetooth every morning

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'd like some help understanding why I have to restart my Mac every morning when I get to work in order for the bluetooth to start working again.  It is a work provided machine, running Yosemite and it has a couple things which I cannot remove as well, like Symantec this and that.  Once I reboot though, I am good all day long and never have a problem with bluetooth.  It is only when I come in to work in the morning, and it is EVERY morning, without fail.

In contrast, my home MacBook, never has this problem.  The difference in machines are that my home machine is several years older (2011 ish), is running El Capitán, and does not run any Symantec anything.  Does anyone have any ideas why I might be having this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you could narrow down when the bluetooth fails - that might help us help you. Apple will give you instructions on how to enable bluetooth diagnostics if you reach out to their support organization.

You might start with generating a diagnostic report each morning when the failure is present. Option click on bluetooth in the menu bar bluetooth icon - and the report will be generated on your desktop.

You might also schedule a shut down and restart each morning if you just with to sidestep the unpleasantness of waiting for the restart. That option is in energy saver in system preferences.

Comment: The diagnostic report is a great idea. I will try that.

Comment: @zeeple Good luck. Feel free to ask a specific question once you've looked over the logs saved. Ping me here with a link to that question if you are so inclined. The debug settings would let you pin down exactly when the bluetooth stack takes a dive if you want to do that work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If left on overnight, perhaps the work machine runs a script of some sort every night and applies changes that affect the functionallity of bluetooth.
Symantec shouldn't be related to the symptoms your machine is experiencing.
It is also possible that the bluetooth chip is faulty (but that's rather unlikely).
Are others experiencing the same or is it just your mac?

Comment: Unfortunately I am one of only two users at my workplace that are on Mac (although, I am very happy that they allow Mac :) but this is a good thought.  I will reach out to the other person and see if she has to reboot in the mornings same as me.  Also, our new IT guy was in the office today, and he was toting a Mac.  I might be able to enlist his help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @zeeple I was just wondering if this question was ever resolved? Upon looking back, I never found an actual answer that worked, let alone any hint as to what had caused it. I deal with mostly iMacs in the office every day but have never come across this issue, perhaps you could let me know how you resolved it in case I'm ever faced with it in the future.

Comment: sadly, the issue has not been resolved.  I rebooted just a few minutes ago in fact.  I am convinced it has something to do with the Symantec garbage my company puts on the macs though.  I cannot imagine what else might be causing the problem.